# how to use Generic relations in DetailView

Tags: django-class-based-views, django-contenttypes

i want to use a comments app in blog with generic ForeignKey
but i don't understand how to implement this in class base views (DetailView)

i'm trying to get the instance id

```
models.py

class Comment(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
          on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, 
                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

content = models.TextField()
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 


views.py

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    title = 'Article Details'
    template_name = 'post-detail.html'
    model = Post
    slug_field = 'slug'
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug_field)
    obj_id = post.id
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, 
           object_id=obj_id)
    context_object_name = 'post'
    extra_context = {
        'title': title,
        'comments': comments,
     }
```

and i get this error:

```
blog.models.Post.DoesNotExist: Post matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass a (comment object) in the template. so we use get_context_data to return (comment)

get_context_data Returns a dictionary representing the template context. The keyword arguments provided will make up the returned context.
to get comment GenericForeignKey  need

1. content_type for Post object
2. post object_id

then we make a query to get comment  **Comment.objects.filter** then pass it to template .

## view

````
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
   template_name = 'Post_detail.html'
   model = Post
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
       post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
       context['comment'] = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id= post.id)
                return context ``` 
    #template Post_detail.html
    {% for comment in comment.all %}
    {{ comment.image }}, {{ comment.image_url }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ post.content}}
    #model 
    class Comment(models.Model):
        content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        content_object = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
        image = models.ImageField()
        image_url = models.URLField()
````

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about your answer? Just providing a code snippet might be hard to grasp.

Comment: post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))  # to get post id

Comment: context['comment'] = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id= post.id) # to get list of the comment for this post